# Ordenar una cadena alfabéticamente usando la libreria de java, es posible?

Tags: java

Necesito ordenar una cadena alfabéticamente. Por las dudas, Java cuanta con algún método que haga esto por mi?

Por ejemplos una cadena como:

```
String cadena = "acdgb";
```

para al final tener una salida: "abcdg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el API estándar no hay una forma de hacerlo llamando a un método de alguna clase de utilidad, o algo por el estilo. Tampoco conozco si existirá alguna biblioteca que te permita hacerlo "bien simple".

Se me ocurre que puede hacerlo tu mismo de un modo relativamente simple utilizando Java 8 en adelante:

```
String cadenaOrdenada = cadena.chars()
                              .sorted()
                              .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                              .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo. Acabo de intentarlo y me tira el error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Seguro que tu variable `String` está en `null`, porque yo lo probé antes de publicar la respuesta, y ahora nuevamente; y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Tenes razón, era eso mismo. Muchas gracias!!